# .NET MVC file does not exist error for URL with extra /text

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have set up a similar friendly URL system to stackoverflow's questions.

The old URL syntax was: localhost:12345:/cars/details/1234

I've already set up the returning 301 and the URL generation but getting a file does not exist error when the url is redirected to:

localhost:12345/cars/details/1234/blue-subaru (because of the last "blue-subaru")

Of course I actually want: localhost:12345/cars/1234/blue-subaru :)

How can I achieve this? Thankyou

Comment: This looks like a routing problem, can you post your routes on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure your route to accept the car's name in RouteTable on the global.asax.

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    "Cars", 
    "Car/{id}/{carName}", 
    new { controller = "Car", action = "Details", id =  UrlParameter.Optional, carName =  UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

And in your `CarController` you could have your Detail action method and get both parameters (id and carName):

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id, string carName) 
{ 
   var model = /* create you model */

   return View(model);
}
```

Your action link should look like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Details", "Car", new { id = 1, carName="Honda-Civic-2013" })
```

Comment: Great answer thankyou. To anyone reading this, I'd also point out, ensure the controller reference "Car" is different to your controller "Cars". Otherwise you'll mess up the routing for that Controller. Also ensure your route is above the default routes in the config file

Answer (score 3):

This is a routing problem so you should little bit changes in your routing like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "Default", // Route nameRegister
               "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "test", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional,name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
           );
```

i think this will help you.